# Git repository showing multiple contributors on new repository?

Tags: git, github

I added a local repository to my git recently and its setting the contributor count to 2. I decided to look who the second one was and it was my old account I had previously used with this GUI.

My old account had no interaction to the repository in question, but is being shown as a contributor. I think maybe the program is confused and has got mixed up here?

The thing that is even more weird is that my old account has more commits and modifications that I've made, all I made was an initial commit, yet my old account has apparently made 2K+ changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a work around, execute this command in your terminal.

```
rd C:\your\repo\path\.git
```

This isn't deleting the file `.git`, but the folder. It just holds holds past history on your repo, along with a much of extra configuration. It's nothing majorly important for you to worry about deleting.

The GUI will rebuild the folder when you link the repo next, without the second contributor. You might have to delete the repo from your git before doing this, so that it actually uploads as a new repo.

Just to make sure all your future commits go smoothly, I would suggest you also give this tab a once over, ensuring you've entered the correct information for commits.

[Click here for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3njA.png)

Answer (score 0):

you have multiple **user.name** and **user.email** configured in git's global configuration.
Try running this:

```
git config --global --replace-all user.name "Your New Name"

git config --global --replace-all user.email "Your new email"
```

and every commit after this point will be in one single name!

Comment: This didn't fix my issue. I've also replaced it inside of the GUI account settings. It seems to only happen on git repository's I've modified some time ago. For example if I made a new one now, it wouldn't show the second contributor.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems to only happen on git repository's I've modified some time ago.

That means at the time commits were done with user.name/email set to your old account.
Or: commits were pushed with that account: if the remote URL was an https one, check your `git config credential.helper`: that old account might still be associated with the remote repo URL.